# drawLayer Method

Tags: iphone

I have drawLayer method, which i'm calling from another method using setNeedsDisplay method, but the flow of code seems to be incorrect.

I have this method

```
  -(IBAction)makeSinglePageMode:(UIButton *)sender
```

from where i'm calling another method

```
  -(void)loadSinglePageWithWidth:(float)width andHeight:(float)height

 which in turn calls `drawLayer` method.
```

I'm attaching the methods.I'm attaching only a part of code in these methods just to have more clarity while understanding the flow.
 After calling [tiledLayer1 setNeedsDisplay]; the flow comes back to  makeSinglePageMode: method without executing drawLayer method. 
The next statement in makeSinglePageMode: method gets executed i.e. [self loadMarkUpFromPageDataSource:pd WithPageSize:pageSize inFrame:markupFrame];
I want this line of code to be executed only after drawLayer method execution is completed.

Any sort of help in this regard will be appreciated.

`
-(IBAction)makeSinglePageMode:(UIButton *)sender{

```
GLogDebug(@"setting size of image to %@", NSStringFromCGSize(aspectFitSize));
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height - __TOP_BRANDING_BAR_HEIGHT)];

[markupView removeAllSubViews];
tiledLayer1.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,768,1024);

[self loadSinglePageWithWidth:(aspectFitSize.width) andHeight:aspectFitSize.height];

GLogDebug(@"markupFrame-%@", NSStringFromCGRect(markupFrame));
[self loadMarkUpFromPageDataSource:pd WithPageSize:pageSize inFrame:markupFrame];
```

}`

```
-(void)loadSinglePageWithWidth:(float)width andHeight:(float)height{

        [tiledLayer1 setNeedsDisplay];
```

}

```
`- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
```

{
    int c=[currentPage intValue]+1;

```
if(c==[kbDataSource numberOfPagesInBook]){
    tiledLayer2.hidden=YES;
}
else tiledLayer2.hidden=NO;



    }



    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(ctx, kCGInterpolationHigh); 
    CGContextSetRenderingIntent(ctx, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, myPageRef);

    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);



}
```

}